# Combinatorial Justification

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n ≥ 2$ be a positive counting number, and consider $σ(n, 2)$.

I have found a single expression for counting the number of surjections from $[n]$ to $[2]$, but am having trouble justifying.

$σ(n, 2)=2^n -2$.
I understand that $2^n$ counts the total number of functions, but if anyone could help me understand why we are subtracting $2$ that would be great!!
Thanks.

Comment: that is (2^n)-2 just to clarify

Comment: How many functions are not surjective? Well, there’s the one that sends everything to $1$, and...

Comment: And the other one that sends everything to 2, wow okay thank you for the help !!